# Silverlight 3 - How to "refresh" a DataGrid content?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have the following scenery:

```
1    using System;
2    using System.Windows;
3    using System.Windows.Controls;
4    using System.Windows.Documents;
5    using System.Windows.Ink;
6    using System.Windows.Input;
7    using System.Windows.Media;
8    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
9    using System.Windows.Shapes;
10   using System.Collections.Generic;
11   
12   namespace refresh
13   {
14      public partial class MainPage : UserControl
15      {
16          
17          List c = new List();
18   
19          public MainPage()
20          {
21              // Required to initialize variables
22              InitializeComponent();
23              c.Add(new Customer{ _nome = "Josimari", _idade = "29"});
24              c.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Wesley", _idade = "26"});
25              c.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Renato",_idade = "31"});    
26              
27              this.dtGrid.ItemsSource = c;
28          }
29   
30          private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
31          {
32              c.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Maiara",_idade = "18"});
33          }
34          
35      }
36      
37      public class Customer
38      {
39          public string _nome{get; set;}
40          public string _idade{get; set;}
41      }
42   }
```

Where, dtGrid is my DataGrid control...

The Question is: How to get the UI Updated after adding one more register to my list.

I get to solve it setting the DataGrid's Item Source to "" and then setting to the list of Customer objects again, like that:

```
1    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
2    
3    {
4    
5    c.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Maiara",_idade = "18"});
6    
7    this.dtGrid.ItemsSource="";
8    
9    this.dtGrid.ItemsSource=c;
10   
11   }
12
```

Is there a way to get the UI updated or the datagrid's itemsSource refreshed automatically after updating, altering or deleting an item from the list c ?

Thank you,

Josimari Martarelli

Answer (score 8):

I recommend looking into binding, INotifyPropertyChanged, DataContexts and ObservableCollection.

1. Change your `List` into an `ObservableCollection`.  That alone will probably solve some of your problems... as an `ObservableCollection` is a little more robust than a simple `List`
2. But, if you want to solve more problems like this, you will look into binding your `DataGrid` to your list of objects through Xaml `<DataGrid... ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">`
3. In order to bind your `DataGrid` to your `List`, you will need to set the `DataContext` of the View.  This can be a simple as placing in your constructor: `this.DataContext = this;`  Setting your `DataContext` tells the view where to look for data when it sees `Binding` statements
4. Then, to solve problems like the one you have (changing something doesn't refresh the view), you will implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your class.  This will allow the code behind to send notifications to the view to tell it when something changes.

Here's the C# code that would implement this:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _MyList = 
        new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> MyList
    {
        get { return _MyList; }  
    } 

    public MainPage()
    {                      
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        MyList.Add(new Customer{ _nome = "Josimari", _idade = "29"});
        MyList.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Wesley", _idade = "26"});
        MyList.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Renato",_idade = "31"});

        OnPropertyChanged("MyList"); // This only works if you use bindings.
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Maiara",_idade = "18"});   

        OnPropertyChanged("MyList"); // This only works if you use bindings.
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Jeremiah,

Even using the 3º Version of Silverlight, is it still necessary using the ObservableCollection to notify property changes?

Thank You,

Josimari Martarelli

Comment: According to the MSDN site ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(VS.95).aspx ) The observable collection should notify when Items are Added or Removed... But it won't notify when items are Updated.  Because of this, I always recommend the pattern of Notifying whenever the list changes.  It's a good habit.  Good luck!